# Can't get mock to execute in vitest

Tags: vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm trying to write a `vitest` test around a composable that reads and writes `postMessage()` for communication between iframes.

The Vue docs say that if the composable relies on lifecycle hooks to mount it in a test app. So I have added `test-helper.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

export function withSetup(composable) {
  let result
  const app = createApp({
    setup() {
      result = composable()
      // suppress missing template warning
      return () => {}
    }
  })
  app.mount(document.createElement('div'))
  // return the result and the app instance
  // for testing provide/unmount
  return [result, app]
}
```

The test creates a mock `messageHandler` which should be executed when the event listener is triggered.

Then I call the `postMessageFromIframe()` method in my composable and test, but I'm getting some unexpected behaviour.

```
import { usePostMessage }  from '@/composables/usePostMessage.ts';
import { vi} from "vitest";
import { withSetup } from './test-helper'
import { nextTick } from 'vue';


describe('usePostMessage', () => {
    it("should deliver a post message successfully", async () => {

        //ARRANGE - create a mock
        const expectedPayload = { action: 'testAction' };

        const messageHandler = vi.fn().mockImplementation(event => {
            // ASSERT within the event handler

            console.log('I was run');
            expect(event.data.from).toBe('usePostMessage');
            expect(event.data.payload.action).toBe(expectedPayload.action);
        });

        //listener
        window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler);

        //ACT
        //launch within app
        const [result,app] = withSetup(() => {
            const { postMessageFromIframe } = usePostMessage();
            postMessageFromIframe({action:'testAction'});
            return { postMessageFromIframe };
        });


        //ASSERT
        // Wait for next tick to allow the event to be processed
        await nextTick();
        expect(messageHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();

        // Cleanup
        window.removeEventListener('message', messageHandler);
        app.unmount();
    });
});
```

If I comment out the last `expect()` then the test runs fine but `messageHandler` is never executed. However if I uncomment the last `expect()` the tests fail but the `messageHandler` is executed. It seems that the last `expect()` is actually executing `messageHandler`. I think I am misunderstanding something here...

Comment: I haven't solved it but it's definitely a timing issue. The event handler is destroyed before the event is triggered.

Then if I also wrap the `toHaveBeenCalled()` method in a timer, it passes

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to test the postMessageFromIframe function synchronously, but the function is asynchronous. You need to await the result of postMessageFromIframe before asserting on it.

Comment: @SaqibShehzad thank you! You led me to the correct answer via a few things. But ultimately it turned out that nextTick() wasn't adequate so I've ended up with the solution below. Thank you for leading me there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that `nextTick()` wasn't enough to wait for all the asynchronous tasks to finish.

I tried adding:

```
        const [result,app] = withSetup(async() => {
            const { postMessageFromIframe } = usePostMessage();
            await postMessageFromIframe(expectedPayload);
            return { postMessageFromIframe };
        });
```

but still no luck.

Final answer was to create a Promise with a 0ms timeout:

```
    it("should deliver a post message successfully", async () => {

        //ARRANGE - create a mock
        const expectedPayload = { action: 'testAction' };
        const messageHandler = vi.fn();
        window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler);

        //ACT
        //launch within app
        const [result,app] = withSetup(() => {
            const { postMessageFromIframe } = usePostMessage();
            postMessageFromIframe(expectedPayload);
            return { postMessageFromIframe };
        });


        // Wait for next tick to allow the event to be processed
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));


        //ASSERT

        expect(messageHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
        const event = messageHandler.mock.calls[0][0];

        expect(event.data.from).toBe('usePostMessage');
        expect(event.data.payload.action).toBe(expectedPayload.action);


        // Cleanup
        app.unmount();
        window.removeEventListener('message', messageHandler);
    });
```